# In snooker does margin of error increase or decrease as the target angle changes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

There is a perception (widely held) in snooker that a straight shot is more difficult than an angled shot. There are many forum discussion about this, and the reasons are usually accepted to be psychological.

But I was wondering, is there a mathematical or mechanical reason for it. Is the margin of error greater when the shot being taken is at an angle?

**Practical Example** - if the white ball was 1 degree off target on a straight shot, and one degree off target on an angled shot (same target for both shots), and each shot hit at the same speed, would the red ball travel off line to the same extent?

Note: I had posted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251189/snooker-shot-does-margin-of-error-increase-or-decrease-as-the-target-angle-inc) on the Mathematics Stack Exchange - there was some helpful discussion around the problem, but I had not figured on factoring in momentum and other physical attributes (was originally just thinking about the angles). I am thinking now that it's more applicable to the physics domain.

Comment: Straight pots aren't desirable because controlling the white ball is harder

Comment: Right,  the equation is conservation of momentum in 1d

Comment: ? No, the I meant conservation of momentum in 1d makes it harder to position cue ball in straight pots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the cue ball is shown to be very close to the target ball due to the size of my piece of paper but I think it shows that the nearer you are to a head on shot the less an error in the direction of the cue ball will affect the direction of the target ball.

[image]

Following one of the answers in Mathematics Stack Exchange using the sine rule for triangle $ABC$ gives $2r\sin(\theta+\phi) = d (\sin \theta)$ where $r$ is the radius of a ball $(26.25 \,\rm mm)$ and $d$ is the separation of the balls centre to centre.

Differentiating this expression one finds that $\dfrac{d\phi}{d\theta}=-1+ \dfrac{a cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-a^2 sin^2\theta}}$ where $a=\dfrac{d}{2r}$.

This equation tells you that for a given value of angle $\theta$ a small change in $\theta$ of $\Delta \theta$ will give you a change in the angle $\phi$ of $\Delta \phi$.

I found it interesting to plot $\dfrac{d\phi}{d\theta}$ as a function of $\theta$ for three values of $a = \dfrac{d}{2r}$ when $d= 0.5\, \rm m, 1\, \rm m,3\, \rm m$, the length of a table being about $3.6\, \rm m$.

[image]

The vertical lines indicate the maximum value of $\theta$ beyond which the cue ball misses the target ball.

The $d = 3 \, \rm m$ graph shows how accurate you have to be to pot a long shot.

This analysis ignores the direction of motion of the cue ball, assumes that the table cloth has no nap, etc, etc.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. The diagram makes it very clear. Thanks a million for that!